# SSJS Array.prototype throws jintException when used with DataExtension.Retrieve value of test

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

I have stumbled across another interesting case with SSJS and Salesforce Marketing Cloud and hope for some ideas on why this occur and furthermore, how I may can prevent this from happening.

On a CloudPage the following SSJS code is throwing an error.

**Code:**

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1");

    Array.prototype.myStuff = function() {};

    try {
        DataExtension.Retrieve({Property:"Name",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"test"});
    } catch(e) {
        Write(Stringify(e));
    }

</script>
```

**Error:**

```
{"message":"Object expected: toLowerCase","jintException":"Jint.Native.JsException: Exception of type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown.\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MethodCall methodCall)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.MethodCall.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MemberExpression expression)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.MemberExpression.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Assign(MemberExpression left, JsInstance value)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(AssignmentExpression statement)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.AssignmentExpression.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(ExpressionStatement statement)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.ExpressionStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(BlockStatement statement)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.BlockStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(ForEachInStatement statement)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.ForEachInStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(BlockStatement statement)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.BlockStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(IfStatement statement)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.IfStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(BlockStatement statement)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.BlockStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.Native.JsFunction.Execute(ExecutionVisitor visitor, JsDictionaryObject that, JsInstance[] parameters)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.ExecuteFunction(JsFunction function, JsDictionaryObject that, JsInstance[] parameters)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MethodCall methodCall)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.MethodCall.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MemberExpression expression)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.MemberExpression.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(ExpressionStatement statement)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.ExpressionStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(BlockStatement statement)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.BlockStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(TryStatement statement)","description":"Jint.Native.JsException: Object expected: toLowerCase\r\nException of type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown. - from Jint\r\n\r\n"}
```

This only happens if two conditions are met:

1. The value of the simple filter is `test`
2. Anywhere in the code an `Array.prototype` is called

If any of these two conditions are not given, the code renders fine.

Some may say, you do not need `Array.prototype` so why bother... well I like to work with `.forEach`, `.includes`,  `.filter` or `.reduce` so I have many polyfills in place.

Does anyone has an idea why this may happen?

Comment: SSJS in SFMC uses ECMAScript v3 from 1999.

Comment: Thanks Adam - that made me laugh :D